# Using ByteBuddy, how do I do the equivalent of MethodCall.invoke(someMethodDescription).onThis()?

Tags: byte-buddy

`MethodCall.invoke(someMethodDescription)` returns an object on which I can, for example, invoke `onSuper()`.  But there is no `onThis()`.  What is the proper recipe to use if I want to invoke a virtual method on an instance of the class being defined?

If it matters, I'm using a subclassing strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For virtual method calls, you can just omit the step and it implicitly invokes the method on the instance being instrumented.